# Prevent application from displaying badge icon in Dock

Tags: macos, dock, notifications

Any Spotify desktop user has likely noticed their pervasive notifications: whenever "one of our friends" joins Spotify, there's both an in-app notification as well as a red badge that appears on Spotify's icon in the Dock.

[image: Spotify Dock icon, with badge, for reference]

**Is there a way to disable an application's ability to show a badge on its Dock icon?**

I'm using Lion (10.7.8), and therefore don't have the 'Notifications' prefpane that was introduced in Mountain Lion.

I tried digging around in the app's resources and .plist file to see if there was a setting to enable/disable this... to no avail.

Comment: Hiding the app's running status also hides badge notifications: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68915/hide-a-running-app-from-dock

Answer (score 4):

No - the normal path is to use the Notifications prefpane to turn off notifications, but this would not help, since Spotify is not listed there.

*I'm also very annoyed by Spotify's constant flood of notifications.* I wonder if there was a way to drop all the social-related network traffic that goes into Spotify and somehow nip these notifications at the bud.

Answer (score 4):

[Answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/194316/70272) solves your problem:

```
# "Usernoted" seems to be the "user notifications daemon", so get it's PID.
pid=$(ps aux | grep -i [u]sernoted | awk '{print $2}')

# Find the sqlite3 database that this program has open. It's in a "private" folder (app sandboxing).
db="$(lsof -p $pid | grep com.apple.notificationcenter/db/db\$ | awk '{print $9}')"

# I got the bundleid from Spotify.app/Contents/Info.plist
bundleid="com.spotify.client"

# I use 0 as the flags because you can change all the settings in System Preferences
# 5 seems to be the default for show_count
# Grab the next-highest sort order
sql="INSERT INTO app_info (bundleid, flags, show_count, sort_order) VALUES ( '$bundleid', 0, 5, (SELECT MAX(sort_order) + 1 FROM app_info) );"

# Run the command
sqlite3 "$db" "$sql"

# Restart usernoted to make the changes take effect
killall user noted
```

Then you can see Spotify in System Preferences -> Notifications, and can disable its notifications.

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks!  However, "Badge app icon" showed up as "off" already (So I'll have to wait for another notification to occur before I can confirm that it worked)