# Have Mountain Lion Messages running but hidden from dock?

Tags: macos, dock, messages, notifications

I use Mountain Lion (10.8.3) Messages exclusively to monitor text messages sent to my cell phone. When I first start my computer or login Messages is hidden (I don't want it in my dock) and if I receive a text message I get a banner alert from notification center. If I open the message I enter the Messages application and the running application shows up in my dock.

What I would like to do is have Messages behave as it does when I first start the computer (receiving notifications but not visible in the dock as running) all of the time (I assume it's running in the background somehow).

If I click 'Hide' on the Messages icon in the doc it remains visible, and if I quit messages entirely after reading a message I stop receiving notifications.

I have tried editing its `Info.plist` to include

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

as suggested in the [Hide a running app from dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68915/hide-a-running-app-from-dock) thread, but the behavior remains the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.8 is a bit more strict than previous versions, with respect to what should be a boolean value.  If you change as below, it should work like you want.

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

Note that in this mode, not only is an app hidden from the dock, but the menu bar does not display either when the program is active.

Comment: Works (although, as you said, it hides more than just the icon from the dock)- Thanks!